# How to programmatically disable S3 public access

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to programmatically remove public access to our S3 bucket using the Java SDK.

I have successfully created our bucket using `s3Client.createBucket(new CreateBucketRequest(bucketName))`.  When I view this bucket in the console (https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home?region=eu-west-2 ) it says "Objects can be public" under "Access".

I've then tried to disable public access using the only method that looks roughly like what I need, namely `deletePublicAccessBlock`, so my line of code is: `s3Client.deletePublicAccessBlock(new DeletePublicAccessBlockRequest().withBucketName(bucketName))`.

After running this code the Console still says "Objects can be public" under "Access".

How do I make this bucket private programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually need PublicAccessBlock. So rather than deletePublicAccessBlock, you need to invoke putPublicAccessBlock in your methods.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html#access-control-block-public-access-examples

Or if you want to just flip the whole account's buckets to no public, you can simply use the account-level public access block, which just flip every single bucket belongs to this account to be private.

Edited:

Example 1 is for bucket level access block and Example 2 is for account level access block.

You need to substitute the 'value' in the example with Boolean:true.

Comment: Thanks, I tried looking at the first link you provide but the code is incomplete (has `<value>`, not sure what to set this to).  Yes I'd be interested in using the account-level public access block.

Comment: Thanks, I checked and it works at the bucket level.  If I wanted to do it at the account level what to put for `<account-id>`??  Is it the same number that I see in the URL of the Login link? Also the number in the top right of the console next to my name? (It has hyphens though)

Comment: It can be the same number that I see in the URL of the Login link -- if you are doing stuff in your root account. To be rest assure, if you click support button on the upper right corner and click support center, the Account number listed in the navbar is the right number to go.